# how to destroy an object in C++

Tags: c++

I have a class for a tetromino in c++. Its a console game and what i do is start off with a line object called b. I then run methods and stuff with b in my game loop based on user input. when the block reaches the ground then i want to destroy it and create a new object called b. this new object b will be a line as well for now. how can i erase that first object so that when i create the new one with the same name, the methods are called on the new object?
so far heres what my code looks like:

```
line b
while(!loss) {
     b.put();
     printmap();
     if(b.collision) {
         delete &b; //delete old b
         line b; //create new object also called b so that the same methods and logic run on this new object
     }
     b.y++;
     b.clear();
     system("cls");
}
```

Comment: Delete `delete &b` is strange, do you want `delete b` instead? And the lifetime of `b` in `line b;` ends at the end of the `{}` limited scope. You probably should create `b` with `b = new line;` and declaire it with `line *b;`, but there is not enough code to be sure. Read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: ...and be aware that `line b; //create new object...` is not the same `b` than the onw you declared at the first line of your code. You are missing some basic knowledge.

Comment: What's wrong with `b = line();`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> delete &b;
> ```

You may not do that. `delete` must only be used on pointers returned from allocating non-array `new`. You did not get `&b` from an allocating new-expression.

---

You could approach the problem from another direction: Since the number of objects doesn't change, it could be much simpler to think of the state of the object changing, instead of destroying and creating a new one. You could simply write a member function that resets the state of the object as desired:

```
if(b.collision) {
     b.reset_state();
}
```

---

That said, it is technically possible to destroy an automatic (or static) variable as long as you create a new one in its place (as is your intention).

The destruction is done by invoking the destructor, while the construction is done using a placement-new expression:

```
b.~line();
new(&b) line;
```

But this approach has more caveats than keeping the single object throughout.

Comment: You don't really need to reset the state - you can assign a new state immediately. If your object's state is never empty, the code has less logic, so maybe better.

Comment: @anatolyg Resetting the state and assigning the state are pretty much the same thing. Resetting merely implies that the new state represents an "initial" state. Which is what OP is looking for as far as I can tell.

Comment: my next object wont necessary be the line object, it is for a tetris game so i i do the second method by calling the deconstructor then will it be able to  create a new object with the same name. for example, if the next object is a square then could i do this? b.~line(); new(&b) square;

Comment: No, it will only work if the objects have the same type ("type" is the correct term to use, not "name"). You might make it work with great care, but it's not recommended. BTW you can ask a separate question on that.

Comment: @anatolyg so essentially, this calls the destructor of the previous object then replaces it with a new one of the same type with the same name right?

Answer (score 5):

Use smart pointers to create and delete your objects. The easiest one to use is `unique_ptr`.

Your code should like something like this:

```
#include <memory>

...
std::unique_ptr<line> b;
while(!loss) {
     b->put();
     printmap();
     if(b->collision) {
         b.reset(new line); // delete old b and create a new object
     }
     b->y++;
     b->clear();
     system("cls");
}
```

The `reset` method of `unique_ptr` takes care of deletion. Also, the last created object will be deleted when your smart pointer goes out of scope.